# Cannot access an application hosted on jBoss remotely

Tags: jboss, rhel5

I have hosted an application in a machine running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5. I started the jBoss AS using the command.

```
./run.sh -b 0.0.0.0
```

and

```
./run.sh -Djboss.bind.address=<<server_address>>
```

and

```
./run.sh --host=<<ipaddress>>
```

but using any of these commands i cannot access the application remotely. Using the the above commands I cannot even access the application on the host machine itself, using localhost as well as ip address. I am not able to figure out the problem here. I can ping the linux machine from the other windows machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check iptables rules are not blocking firstly

Also are you running as a user? If so, you will not have permission to bind to a port number less than 1024.

try telneting the port from the server itself to check the service is responding e.g.

```
telnet localhost 8080
```

presuming that you are running on 8080 in the example above.

you can drop your iptables temporarily for testing if it is safe to do so by:

```
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

and restart them when you've finished with

```
/etc/init.d/iptables start
```

you can make a permanent change to your iptables config by adding the following line to /etc/sysconfig/iptables

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: i am running as root.. and yes after dropping the iptables i am able to access it :) thank you. Is there a method to open the port 8080 securely ??

Comment: I tend to modify the iptables config manually. It's /etc/sysconfig/iptables

Comment: Adding a line like so will enable port 8080 access to new connections from outside:   -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

Comment: I anyway went to System->Administration->Selinux and Firewall and added 8080 port in other port section and its working fine now..